Movie about a woman killing her mom, husband and sister and going insane
Basically at the beginning its these 2 girls they walk up to a house and knock on the door. Nobody answers so the girl grabs her key and opens the door and walks in.
She saw blood so she keeps walking and she finds her mom dead. After it cuts off and she's at her house. I think if I remember right she keeps seeing dead animals and I think body parts around her house.
It ends up being wolves eating stuff or something she lives out in the middle of nowhere.
Then a while into the movie it starts going further into that night where she finds her mother dead and it shows the same clip but with one more event happening the out the movie. One part I remember specifically she's laying in bed and her husband and sister bring her breakfast in bed and they're all nice and sweet to her and stuff.
Then her sister says "oh remember the thing" and her husband replies with "oh yes how could I ever forget". He grabs an ax and slams it right in her face and blood goes everywhere.
Anyways at the very end of the movie after showing all the clips of her mom in the bathtub it finally reveals that she ended up killing her mom because her mom slept with her husband and she kills her sister and husband afterwards and after it shows that clip it shows a bunch of clips showing that this whole time she went insane after she killed everyone and she started dancing with the dead bodies and ate at a table with them and stuff. 

Welcome to Movies&TV. That's broad plot details. Good. Do you remember language, country or other plot details, any at all? Add them so that it can help identify this movie. Also see How to ask Identify-this-X questions.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
